# Android: show a notification due to an external action

Tags: java, android, android-activity, notifications, lifecycle

I have to show a notification when my MainActivity is onPause() so i write the code below on my MainActivity, so by onPAuse() i mean the Activity is interrupted due to an external action (missed call, screen lock) but i have a problem, even when i move to another activity the notification is shown, can some one help me.

```
private void createNotify(){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Radio Jawhara en cours...", System.currentTimeMillis());  
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, FragmentsSliderActivity.class), 0);
    String titreNotification = "Radio Jawhara en cours...";
    String texteNotification = "Retour à la radio...";   
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, titreNotification, texteNotification, pendingIntent);
    notification.vibrate = new long[] {0,200,100,200,100,200};
    notificationManager.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION, notification);
}

private void cancelNotify(){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(ID_NOTIFICATION);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    cancelNotify();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    createNotify();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `FLAG` in your code and modify your `onPause()` as below:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(FLAG) {
        createNotify();
    }
}
```

Set default value of this flag to `false` and set it to `true` **ONLY when you** want to navigate away from this `Activity`. (e.g. when you are starting another `activity` by `startActivity()`);

Comment: Thanky you fo your quick response, i undrestand the idea but how do i know if i have called startActivity() so i can turn the FLAG to true ?

Comment: It is you who would be calling `startActivity()` based on some event/condition within your code so you would know.

Comment: I have that FragmentsSliderActivity class which include the TabsAdapter for my all fragments and i have 4 other activities, so i am putting the FLAG on my MAinActivity (FragmentsSliderActivity) and i have to prevent the Notification to be show when starting th other 4 activities.

Comment: There are two possibilities when your `MainActivity` will go into `onPause()`: 1. External action and 2. when you start a new activity.
In both cases you don't want the notification. Then when exactly you want the notification? OR can you tell me exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No, i went notification when my activity in onPasue due to an external action, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you're managing this within one activity of several, and you should be managing it at a higher level.

If I were to solve this, I would create a singleton class to manage the notification. All of my activities would (in their onPause() method) tell the singleton that they've paused, and all of my activities would also tell the singleton (in their onResume() method) that they've resumed.

My singleton's pause method would not create the notification immediately; instead it would set a timer for a reasonable amount of time to get to the next of my activities (perhaps 1 second). My singleton's resume method would simply cancel that timer. If the timer expires (which would happen one second after being paused for some external purpose), it would create the notification.

To make this easier, I might instead extend Activity with a class that has static details instead of using a singleton, and my other activities would extend from this instead of extending Activity. This would make it much easier to create and maintain properly coordinated activities.

Comment: what this mean "To make this easier, I might instead extend Activity with a class that has static details instead of using a singleton, and my other activities would extend from this instead of extending Activity. This would make it much easier to create and maintain properly coordinated activities." and how can i make it ?